# How do I use $_GET[] with require("doc.php")?

Tags: php, html, get

I have a page that is dynamically loading a `.php` document when a trigger is called.

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["userId"])) {
        require("claimWithUserId.php");
    }
?>
```

and inside of that `.php` doc I am trying to get a variable with `$_GET[]` but nothing is returning.

```php
<p>Your name is <?php $_GET["userId"] ?>.</p>
```

If the variable is incorrect I get an error so I know it can at least see the variable, and when I had the same code included in my main document it was returning the variable just fine. Does anyone know why the variable isn't being passed through or what I can do to pass this variable?

Let me know if you need more info or context. Thanks!

Comment: You need to `echo` the value: `<?php echo $_GET["userId"] ?>`

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why it was working without echo when I had it in my original document, but his has fixed it here.

Comment: "_I'm not sure why it was working without echo_" Pretty sure it wasn't! ;) (Or you might have used something like `<?= $_GET["userId"] ?>` - which is short for the above)

Comment: I'm realizing in the original, the whole thing was inside an `echo` (e.g. `echo <p>Your name is ", $_GET["userId"], ".</p>";`) so using `echo` again there would've been redundant. Sorry, I'm pretty new to `.php`. Thanks for your help tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not printing the variable. `<?php $_GET["userId"] ?>` will not print anything. But `<?php echo $_GET["userId"] ?>` will do.

Secondly, you don't need to pass the variable to the second `.php` file. The variable is available automatically to the second `.php` file. You can achieve this like below-

In the first `.php` file-

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["userId"])) {
    $userId = $_GET["userId"];
    require("claimWithUserId.php");
}
```

In the second `claimWithUserId.php` file-

```
<?php
echo isset($userId) ? $userId : '';
```

Always sanitize $_GET data before processing.